# ListView sorting by two columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a model class `Reminder`:

```
public class Reminder 
{
    public string ReminderName { get; set; }
    public ReminderTypes ReminderType { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReminderDate { get; set; }
}
```

and I also have an enum called `ReminderTypes`:

```
public enum ReminderTypes 
{
    REMINDER_NORMAL,
    REMINDER_FLAGGED,
    REMINDER_IMPORTANT,
    REMINDER_WARNING
}
```

I created my list as follows.

```
List<Reminder> reminders = new List<Reminder> {
    new Reminder{ ReminderName = "Reminder1",  ReminderType = ReminderTypes.REMINDER_FLAGGED , ReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
    },
    new Reminder{ ReminderName = "Reminder2", ReminderType = ReminderTypes.REMINDER_IMPORTANT, ReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).AddHours(5).AddMinutes(50)
    },
    new Reminder{ ReminderName = "Reminder3", ReminderType = ReminderTypes.REMINDER_NORMAL, ReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5)
    },
    new Reminder{ ReminderName = "Reminder4", ReminderType = ReminderTypes.REMINDER_WARNING, ReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).AddHours(5).AddMinutes(49)
    },
    new Reminder{ ReminderName = "Reminder5", ReminderType = ReminderTypes.REMINDER_FLAGGED, ReminderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).AddHours(5)
    },
};
ListViewReminder.ItemsSource = reminders;
```

The sorting rule that should be:

1. Always flagged ones must be on top (flagged ones should be sorted by time)
2. Those that are not flagged should be sorted by current time (those close to current time should be on top)

The view that should be in listview:

- Reminder1 ( Becuse flagged and Closer date than the other flagged.)
- Reminder5 ( Because flagged )
- Reminder3 ( Non-flagged, Closer date than the other non-flagged )
- Reminder4
- Reminder2

How can I do that?

Comment: `(Those close to current time should be on top.)` - does this include times in the past? So a time one minute ago should be listed before a time two minutes in the future - but a time two minutes ago should be listed AFTER a time on minute in the future?

Comment: No. Because the past will be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Achieve this using `System.Linq`,

```
var Result = reminders
            .Where(e => e.ReminderType == ReminderTypes.REMINDER_FLAGGED)
            .OrderBy(e => e.ReminderDate).ToList();
Result.AddRange(reminders
    .Where(e => e.ReminderType != ReminderTypes.REMINDER_FLAGGED)
    .OrderBy(e => e.ReminderDate));
```

Comment: It is giving the expected `Reminder1 , Reminder5, Reminder3, Reminder4, Reminder2`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two changes.

1. Assign numbers to your enums so they sort how you want them sorted.
2. Use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to sort your list based on `ReminderType`, then `ReminderDate`.

```
    public enum ReminderTypes
    {
        REMINDER_FLAGGED = 0,
        REMINDER_NORMAL = 1,
        REMINDER_WARNING = 2,
        REMINDER_IMPORTANT = 3
    }
```

```
    List<Reminder> ordered = reminders.OrderBy(x => x.ReminderType).ThenBy(x => x.ReminderDate).ToList();
    ordered.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ReminderName));
```

**Output**

```
Reminder1
Reminder5
Reminder3
Reminder4
Reminder2
```

Comment: If there any `ReminderTypes` has value less than `REMINDER_FLAGGED`. it will give the unexpected result. e.g `REMINDER_ABC`

Comment: Updated the enums to start with 0.

Comment: `ReminderTypes` may be saved DB. So, Don't change it blindly. And There Id may be having constants in Enum